# How would I make a binary search tree work with a list of alphabetized words for a spell checker?

Tags: c

Mainly what I'm asking is, does the root node have to be equal to NULL to make leaves of characters ranging from a-z? From the examples online, the root node is a specific letter, for this example 'a', and then everything else follows. Though, how would I then create the words that start with the letter 'b'?

What I had in mind was have NULL be the root node, then say you had cap, carts, cat. You'd make a tree going:

```
NULL -> 'c' -> 'a' -> 'p' -> '\0'
```

then, you implement carts, by checking string[n] until it doesn't equal the letter in the tree and makes a new leaf and continues.

```
NULL -> 'c' -> 'a' -> 'p' -> '\0'
                |
                v
               'r' -> 't' -> 's' -> '\0'
```

now lets say I want to add a word that doesn't start with c, like pen.

```
'p'  -> 'e' -> 'n' -> '\0'
 ^
 |
NULL -> 'c' -> 'a' -> 'p' -> '\0'
                |
                v
               'r' -> 't' -> 's' -> '\0'
```

Am I on the right path with this?

Comment: The answer is no. NULL never points to anything useful

Comment: But a `head` pointer - initialized to NULL - would make sense

Comment: Oh, so make a head pointer equal to NULL and follow the rest of what I was doing?

Comment: There is no "this is the answer" to your question. Sorry. It can be implemented in many different ways. A simple tree would go left or right until you find a match. If no no match, a new node would be added

Comment: Anyway - yes, you'll always need a `head` pointer. It starts at `NULL` When the first new test is added, the `head` change from `NULL` to point to the character

Comment: If you have any "so far code" post it

Comment: Can you show me a visual representation? I'm just trying to get an idea first before I start coding. Pseudocode basically.

Comment: Your own visual representation is fine. You just need to change `NULL` to `head` and you'll be fine

Comment: head is technically NULL since you use it as a pointer to a letter of each string and then place it in a spot with each additional leaf right?

Comment: Well, I can't post an answer as you have posted no code! But... The first word added should give you a `head` pointing to the the first character of the first word. The second word may give a new left/write node OR follow the path of the first the word

Comment: Two questions. **1.** How do you imagine a graph for the set of words 'boxer', 'bowman', 'boat' and 'bottle'? Or, how would it look like if you put 'cap' and 'carts', and then add 'camp'? And 'calf'? **2.** Are you sure you meant a root node NULL (which in C language means 'an empty pointer, pointing nowhere') and not NUL ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) mnemonic denoting a 'character' with code zero, i.e. a 'no character')...?

Comment: What you are really talking about is a TRIE tree or ternary search tree that provides prefix searching to allow you to collect a list of possible completions based on the first X number of characters. A TRIE has significant memory requirements. A ternary search tree is optimal but non-trivial to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use a binary tree to store words because there can be more than two distinct letters after a letter.

What you need is called an *m-ary tree*. See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree) for a description.

Regarding the NULL at the start, it doesn’t make much sense. The root pointer must hold the address of the top node of the tree. It can’t be NULL if the tree is not empty.

It is unclear from you explanation if the NULL was for the letter. Anyway, a binary tree can have only at most two distinct successors to a node.